# how to auto reboot with a interactive section?

Tags: automation

the auto installation runs perfectly with customize user-data, but it won't auto reboot when install complete.

I find no documents about reboot in https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference

and I also find an article here http://junyelee.blogspot.com/2021/05/subiquity.html

`# use interactive-sections to avoid an automatic reboot`

and here is my user-data

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  ### config storage and network manually
  interactive-sections:
    - storage
  # Swapfile on root volume
  swap:
    swap: 16GB
  late-commands:
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- apt-get --purge -y --quiet=2 remove byobu
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- apt-get install -y git wget curl rsync net-tools ssh ubuntu-desktop plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo grub-gfxpayload-lists mailutils
    - curtin in-target --target=/target -- hostnamectl set-hostname ubuntu-jammy.abc.com
  # Write a script that can take care of some post install setup "late-commands" cannot be interactive unfortunately"
    - |
      cat <<EOF | sudo tee /target/etc/finish-install-setup.sh
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      echo *************************
      echo ****  Finish Setup   ****
      echo *************************
      echo 'Enter the hostname for this system: '
      read NEW_HOSTNAME
      hostnamectl set-hostname \${NEW_HOSTNAME}
      echo
      echo 'Enter the timezone for this system: '
      echo 'Asia/Taipei'
      read NEW_TIMEZONE
      timedatectl set-timezone \${NEW_TIMEZONE}
      echo *************************
      echo
      echo *************************
      echo 'Restarting to finish ...'
      shutdown -r 3
      EOF
    - curtin in-target --target /target chmod 744 /etc/finish-install-setup.sh
  apt:
    disable_components: []
    geoip: true
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
    - arches:
      - amd64
      - i386
      uri: http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu
    - arches:
      - default
      uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
  drivers:
    install: false
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu-jammy
    password: somesupersecretpasswordhere
    realname: administrator
    username: administrator
  kernel:
    package: linux-generic
  keyboard:
    layout: us
    toggle: null
    variant: ''
  locale: en_US.UTF-8
  network:
    ethernets:
      ens18:
        dhcp4: true
    version: 2
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys: []
    install-server: true
  ### user-data , commands run during first boot
  user-data:
    runcmd:
      - rm -rf  /usr/bin/python
      - ln -s /usr/bin/python3.10 usr/bin/python
      - wget https://download.nomachine.com/download/7.8/Linux/nomachine_7.8.2_1_amd64.deb -O /opt/nomachine.deb
      - dpkg -i /opt/nomachine.deb
      #- /etc/finish-install-setup.sh
  version: 1
```

I have to press enter at the end to reboot machine , which I don't think it's a good "automation".

But I need to configure storage layout manually , is there any solutions the force to reboot after the installation complete ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify any `interactive-sections` then the installer (*subiquity*) [considers the installation "interactive"](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/a9ac5a5fb28168aa328e2f9453b1f4768fd4e54c/subiquity/server/server.py#L659).  If the installation is "interactive" then the installer will [wait for the user](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/428dc9502f8d569700e2f4ff71c618d027465c34/subiquity/server/controllers/shutdown.py#L87) to click Reboot when the installation is complete.

The simple way to reboot anyway is to use `late-commands` to call `/sbin/reboot`.  The downside is that the installer does not get to finish, and any installation steps performed after `late-commands` will not happen.  I believe the only step that will get skipped is copying the installer logs to the installed system.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  late-commands:
    - |
      /sbin/reboot
```

A more kludgy method is to simulate the Reboot click.  The client *subiquity* process communicates this event to the server *subiquity* process using a socket at `/run/subiquity/socket`.  Here is an example `late-command` that simulates the client communication so the server believes the user has requested a reboot.  In this example the `curl` process will block, which is why it is run in the background using `screen`.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  late-commands:
    - |
      screen -dmS reboot curl --unix-socket /run/subiquity/socket -X POST http://a/shutdown?mode=%22REBOOT%22 --header "Content-Type:application/octet-stream"
      true
```

**notes**

I tested using Ubuntu 22.04 (`subiquity 22.04.2`)

Comment: thanks , I will try to understand reboot in the late-command .